# Gson reading cannot resolve object Map field

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to read json into object.

**test.json**:

```
{
  "errorCode": "503",
  "errorMessage": "ERR_MESSAGE",
  "entities": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
}
```

This is the **ErrorDetail** model I want to create from json:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ErrorDetail {
    private String errorCode;
    private String errorMessage;
    private Map<String, List<String>> entities;
    private String errorSource;
}
```

common **main** method to test the parsing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/main/resources/test.json")));
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ErrorDetail errorDetail = gson.fromJson(json, ErrorDetail.class);
        System.out.println(errorDetail);
}
```

However I'm getting the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 5 column 14 path $.entities.
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:817)
    at com.nordstrom.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 5 column 14 path $.entities.
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:351)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:80)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:187)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
    ... 5 more
```

What am I doing wrong? Please assist, I've been debugging and looking for solutions all day and no results.

Comment: The `entities` as definied in your example json is of type `Map<String, String>`, not `Map<String, List<String>>`, which confirms the exception `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING` you are getting

Comment: @3r1c Considering it's an error detail model it's very likely that `key1` and `key2` are placeholders for dynamic key names

Comment: Thank you. By the way, if I actually need a List<String> my values should be in square brackets for each key, recently found this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an incorrect model. It should be the following:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ErrorDetail {
    private String errorCode;
    private String errorMessage;
    // private Map<String, List<String>> entities;
    private Map<String, String> entities;
    private String errorSource;
}
```